# Where can I find code that will let me know when an email is opened that will work for a large number of recipients?

Tags: java, email, tracking, html-email, email-client

If I send someone an email I'd like to know if they have read it. We have a large number of clients and need to be able to send thousands of emails at once.

We are not using gmail, outlook or any other email client that supports this functionality. Switching email providers is not an option, at least in the short term. What we need is similar to read receipt in outlook or oracle plugin for gmail. I think the right solution is some code to embed in the email, but haven't found anything that works. Services like didtheyreadit.com just get the email sent to spam folders and others don't send to enough addresses or charge too much.

Any help in solving this problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The general approach is to add a unique image url into the html of each email.

Then all you have to do is configure your web server to serve a single pixel image for each of these requests.

Then examine your web logs and bingo - by tying the unique image url's to recipients and you'll have a list of those who opened the email (and viewed the images).